# C# getting a checkbox value from one form to another

Tags: c#, forms, checkbox

After hours of puzzling I think I have missed the obvious here. I am sure it is not this difficult. I have a Form (CommTester) that has a checkbox on it. On this same form I have a ToolStrip with an item that will start another form (SetPrintGoDelay). This form needs to know if the checkbox on form 1 is checked or not. The snippet below shows how I am trying to get the CommTester Form and send it to SetPrintGoDelay Form. (All code has large amounts cut out to make it fit easier, ask if you think I have missed a vital bit out)

```
    namespace comms_test
    {
       public partial class CommTester : Form
      {
           public CommTester()
           {
               InitializeComponent();
               EnableControls();
               btn_connect.Visible = true;
               btn_disconnect.Visible = false;
               toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Disconnected";
          }

    private void chkbx_log_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
           {
               SetPrintGoDelay form2;
               form2 = new SetPrintGoDelay(this);
               form2.Show();
           }

    public string checkboxchecked()
    {
        if (chkbx_log.Checked == true)
        {
            return "1";
        }
        else
        {
            return "0";
        }
    }

   }
   }
```

Now in the SetPrintGoDelay Form

```
namespace comms_test
{


public partial class SetPrintGoDelay : Form
{

    CommTester main;        


    public SetPrintGoDelay(CommTester incomingform)
    {
       InitializeComponent();
       main = incomingform;
       MessageBox.Show(main.checkboxchecked().ToString());
    }

     private void btn_setprintgodelay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (main.checkboxchecked().ToString() == "1")
        {
            CommTester frm1 = new CommTester();
            frm1.log_data(DataToLog); //go and log the data
        }
     }
```

So on the CommTester Form I tick the checkbox and I get it logging the data but immediately it is done the checkbox value is set to 0 and it will not pick it up again as 1 even though it is still checked. I think we may have disposed of it and I do not seem to be able to get the value again. As I say after hours of trying things I am obviously missing the obvious. If there is an easier way of getting the value of checkbox from one form to another please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

The form will not have been disposed (unless you are doing that elsewhere in the code you omitted) because you are holding onto a reference in SetPrintGoDelay.  I would suggest that instead of passing a "0" or "1" string indicating whether or not the checkbox is checked, use a boolean property.  If nothing else, that would clarify what is going on.

What happens if you make these changes?

In CommTester:

```
public bool IsCheckboxChecked
{
    get { return chkbx_log.Checked; }
}
```

and in SetPrintGoDelay:

```
private void btn_setprintgodelay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (main.IsCheckboxChecked)
    {
        CommTester frm1 = new CommTester();
        frm1.log_data(DataToLog); //go and log the data
    }
 }
```